# How to extract attribute from a XML field with Subsonic?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, subsonic

I have a SQL query like this :

```
SELECT      
     myXmlField.value('(./row/@myAttribute)[1]', 'nVarchar(max)') as myAttribute
FROM myTABLE
   Where myID = 640
```

The SQL query works fine, but now, how can I extract the attribute from the XML field that I have in MS SQL Server, with Subsonic?

I am using Visual Studio 2005, .net 2.0, C#, and SubSonic 2.1.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I solved it loading the value of the XML field, subsonic returns it as a string, in a XmlDocument object.

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(MyTable.myXmlField); //MyTable entitie created by subsonic.
doc.SelectSingleNode("./row/@myAttribute").Value //Here I get the attribute from the XML field.
```

Any other way to do it?

Comment: See my answer. I'll add that what you are doing is pretty horribly ineffecent in lots of ways. You are creating a whole dom document in memory to extract a single value. You should probably use a regex here, if not an XmlTextReader.

Answer (score 1):

That is quite a bit beyond subsonic or any other ORM I can think of -- selecting from within an XML column is a very database server specific issue.

Best bet would be to create a stored procedure that executes that SQL and let subsonic call that.